# Get Object Values

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I use this code:

```
$currency = new MyCurrency();
print_r($currency);
```

to load/print the following Object:

```
MyCurrency Object (
[currencyCode:protected] => EUR
[currencies:protected] => Array (
[USD] => Array ( [currency_id] => 1 [currency_name] => US Dollar [left_symbol] => $  [exchanged_value] => 1.12000000 )
[EUR] => Array ( [currency_id] => 2 [currency_name] => Euro [left_symbol] =>  €  [exchanged_value] => 1.00000000 )
[GBP] => Array ( [currency_id] => 3 [currency_name] => Pound Sterling [left_symbol] => £  [exchanged_value] => 0.89999998 )
))
```

I am trying to get the active currency [currencyCode:protected] =>EUR and values from the Array [currencies:protected] but fail no matter what.

Can i get the values to variables in the way that i am trying?
(The following are definitely wrong but they are an example of what i am trying)

```
$active_currency = $currency->currencyCode;
$USD_icon = $currency->currencies[USD]->left_symbol;
$USD_value = $currency->currencies[USD]->exchanged_value;
```

Comment: With native php, you have a few options (some more hacky than others) https://stackoverflow.com/q/20334355/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the class and use a public function in order to get the values that i needed the correct way.

```
$currency = new MyCurrency();
$active_currency = $currency->getCurrencyCode();
```

Comment: Please award the green tick to your own answer so that the Community will stop bumping this question to the top of the unresolved list.